# Automatically generating Customer Attribute Form Fields

Tags: magento

When you add customer attributes, Magento's admin dashboard for customer's automatically generates the relative form element for that new attribute.

Is there a way to do the same thing on the front end via a controller in a module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nope, the frontend customer fields are hard coded, check out the phtml inside customer/form to see it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if Varien_Form or even Zend_Form could be leveraged at all.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Customer attributes are displayed on the form if "Show on frontend" is enabled. However those fields aren't saved from frontend by default. You need to extend fieldsets in your module for that, see config.xml in core Mage/Customer module

**EDIT**: actually that is true for enterprise edition, on CE you have to edit register.phtml (preferably by making a copy in your theme)

Comment: I have setup additional customer attributes and was curious how to automatically render the HTML for these fields without hardcoding it into the frontend templates (e.g. register.phtml).  It looks like its a combination of fieldsets in config.xml with possibly having PE or EE.